# VBA RemoveDuplicates to remove the whole row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a ticker list, which needs updating every month or so. That list is compiled from a number of equity indexes, and therefore contains duplicates.

The data is in columns A & B where A has the ticker and B has the company name.

```
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Set wsSource = Sheets("TickerList")

wsSource.Columns(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
```

Two issues:

1. The code above doesn't remove the duplicates in column A (tried Columns("A") also)
2. I need to test for duplicate in column A, BUT delete the whole row when the duplicate is detected.

Any help appreciated, my VBA is rusty.

Update:
Columns call doesn't work, changed code to the following

```
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Set wsSource = Sheets("TickerList")
Set tickerRange = wsSource.Range(Range("A1"), Range("B1").End(xlDown))
    tickerRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
```

and that code works. Not sure why Range.RemoveDuplicates works but Columns.RemoveDuplicates doesn't. I found dozens of examples of it while googling.

Comment: To remove rows in columns A:G based on A duplicates you can use `Range("A:G").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1`, but its uncleat why the given code doesn't remove duplicates in column A, that's exactly what it should do.

Comment: do you have multiple workbooks open? if you dont specify `ThisWorkbook.Sheets` then it wont necessarily refer to the current workbook

Comment: @BrakNicku...I know. I've used RemoveDuplicates hundreds of times, but it is not working, and I did reboot, to no avail

Comment: @BrakNicku... See my update

Comment: Maybe you have merged cells and `on error resume next` somewhere in the code. It is my only idea why the first snippet did not remove duplicates.

Comment: You might get an error if part of column A is a table and the rest isn't. Is this the case? If it is, that would explain why `Range.RemoveDuplicates` works and `Columns.RemoveDuplicates` doesn't. Using `LastRow` makes sure that you only work inside the table.

Comment: stick with the `Range` method anyway. running methods on entire columns when not necessary is a foolish waste of resources.

Comment: Did you already check if your entries are equal indeed (using the `Match()` worksheet function, e.g.), maybe there are differences you don't see.